# Is there any way to run java awt application on macos without taking focus

Tags: java, macos, awt, toolkit, awtrobot

I have simple java application

```
main(){
Robot robot = new Robot();
Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

It grabs focus from my other java application when i run it on macosx. Can i prevent it?
It is also possible to paste Toolkit.getDefaultTookit instead of Robot with same effect.

Answer (score 2):

You should set property apple.awt.UIElement equals true  by "`java -Dapple.awt.UIElement=true`" or by `System.setProperty()`

Comment: From [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/java/Reference/Java_PropertiesRef/Articles/JavaSystemProperties.html); UIElement "Suppresses the normal application Dock icon and menu bar from appearing. Only appropriate for background applications which show a tray icon or other alternate user interface for accessing the apps windows. Unlike `java.awt.headless=true`, this does not suppress windows and dialogs from actually appearing on screen.
The default value is false."